# Can I delete all the files in zsh-autosuggestions installing it?

Tags: terminal, shell, zsh

I am using zsh as the default shell for my Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop LTS terminal. I am using `zsh-autosuggestions`, which is from https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions.
I cloned the repository into my `~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions` folder, and I found a lot of files there. I added `source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh` to my `.zshrc` file and everything is working fine. Now, my question is, can I delete all other files in the `~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/` folder, leaving the `zsh-autosuggestions.zsh` file alone, because I am sourcing only that file ?
Or all the other files are required for the `zsh-autosuggestions.zsh` file to work properly ?

And also, I have the same question for `zsh-syntax-highlighting` which is from https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.
Since both of these are from the same developers, I assume that they both should have the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you call only a program’s `main()` method, can you then delete all the other source code, yet still maintain a functioning program?

The proof is left as an exercise for the reader.